# Highchart timedate format

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, highcharts, timestamp

I'm almost done with my highchart, but I can't manage to get the datetime/timestamp look correct. im not sure if its the format for the xAxis, or if its the format for the serie.

[image]

My data:
`[{"x":"2016-04-08 12:11:02","y":32},{"x":"2016-04-08 14:22:07","y":2},{"x":"2016-04-11 10:10:06","y":4},{"x":"2016-04-11 11:56:35","y":2},{"x":"2016-04-11 12:16:20","y":2},{"x":"2016-04-11 14:09:27","y":2},{"x":"2016-04-11 15:03:31","y":1},{"x":"2016-04-11 20:18:41","y":1172},{"x":"2016-04-11 21:00:06","y":1014}]`

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        title : {
            text : 'test'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'signups',
            data : data,
            turboThreshold : 0
        }]
    });
```

Im sure its a minor thing I am missing. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't understand the format of your timestamp, hence it shows milliseconds from unix time (1 jan 1970). Either for each point create new Date(your timestamp) or pass the time in epoch milliseconds.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share the fiddle.

Comment: So that's maybe wh.., it wants the time in unixtime but I give it in yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss.

Comment: The point  should be in format: [timestamp, value] or {x: timestmap, value}, where value is number and timestamp is time in miliseconds (i.e returned by Date.UTC());. So you need to convert your dates into correct format in back-end or during preprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your date convert it to [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/UTC)

```
var date = new Date(yourData[i].x);
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds)));
```

Then insert it to your series
May be quite long but, it will work.
Look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/v9kcm9t1/1/):