# Highcharts showing wrong time based on timezone

Tags: php, highcharts

I am bringing in data that looks like this via PHP:

```
Sun Jun 26 02:00:01 EDT 2016
```

It becomes this variable:

```
    $arr_dates[] = date("m/d/Y H:i", strtotime($datestr, time()));
```

And becomes used in Highcharts:

```
        series: [{
            name: '# users online',
            data: [<?php echo "\n"; foreach ( $arr_num_users as $i ) { echo "[Date.parse('".$arr_dates[$ct]."'),".$i."],\n";$ct++; } echo "\n]"; ?>
        }
```

So when I (EDT timezone) view it, the graph shows up correctly and the times are displayed as GMT+0.

But anyone else using a different timezone, the times are off. So someone in PDT will see a graph that is skewed by 3 hours which is incorrect. It should always be a set time, or at least accurate.

How can I fix this? `setUTC` did not seem to help.

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
       global: {
            useUTC: true
       }
    });
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
                    rangeSelector : {
                            selected : 1
                    },
.....
```

I've also tried without any `setOptions` at all, nothing changes.

This is under Highcharts v3.0.10

To be clear, the time on the chart is changing based on the users' timezone. I do not want that to happen.

You can view the issue here: http://observit.org/rffxiv.php (switch to EDT for your timezone which displays correctly, then to something else and refresh; issue will be shown)

Comment: I believe you need to know the users timezone. And as far as I know you need javascript for that, or possible ajax. Have never tried to get users timezone so I don't know.

Comment: @Andreas I don't remember Highcharts mentioning that, weird.

Comment: I'm not talking specific highcharts, I'm talking general webdeveloping.

Comment: @Andreas Well, I don't really want to know their timezone because I want the date timezone static. I don't want it changing based on their timezone, but it's doing that and I don't know why.

Comment: In that case I misunderstood you. sorry

Comment: @Zeno, I've answered a relative question 2 month ago. Maybe it can help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618999/highchart-timedate-format/36646971#36646971. Let me know if it's ok

Comment: Have you tried to disable [UTC time](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC) or use [moment.js](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: @SebastianBochan Isn't that already being done in my code?

Comment: @IsraGab I'm confused, I already have the dates formatted correctly. Isn't that what your answer does?

Comment: it does. But it looks like this is your issue

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        timezoneOffset: 5 * 60 //EST offset
    }
});
```

Comment: That does not work. The time on the chart is still changing based on the client timezone. I do not want that to happen.